# Where is the option in Visual Studio 2019 to have Ctrl-K Ctrl-D not make stylistic changes to VB.NET code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When I press Ctrl-K Ctrl-D, Visual Studio formats my VB.NET code, same as it does with C#, but it also makes some other changes that I'd like to disable because they are making it hard to see actual changes in source control. For instance, it adds parentheses after method calls:

```
connection.Close
```

becomes

```
connection.Close()
```

and spaces are added around operators:

```
"answer is "&42
```

becomes

```
"answer is " & 42
```

There's got to be some option to disable these changes but I'm having trouble finding it...

Comment: Formatting preferences are set with Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > Code Style.  Not these ones though, byte that bullet just once to get it over with.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, the code of VB.net is automatically formatted by default. If you want to cancel the automatic formatting, taking Visual Studio 2017 as an example, you can change the settings as follows.

[image]

[image]

If you write code after that, the code will not be automatically formatted.

[image]

[image]

As for Ctrl-K Ctrl-D, you can disable them in the following steps:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not clear - I don't want to disable code formatting when pressing Ctrl-K Ctrl-D entirely; I just want to disable all these stylistic changes that are made to the code, such as adding parentheses after method calls, spaces around operators, that sort of thing. I would like it however to adjust tabs to make the code look nicer, as is done with C# code. Am I correct in surmising that there is no way to adjust the settings in this fashion?

Comment: Do you mean to customize Edit.FormatDocument by pressing Ctrl-K Ctrl-D?

Comment: Yes, I would like to customize the behavior of Edit.FormatDocument. Is this possible?